# How do I use millis() in Arduino to get the time between two points in a graph?

Tags: timer, arduino, microcontroller, interrupt, arduino-uno

I am writing a program where the Arduino will start a timer using millis() when the voltage on the analogue pin A2 rises and crosses a threshold and turns off the timer when threshold is crossed again (rising voltage). It will then calculate the time = t2-t1. I thought about using external interrupt and an op-amp to detect the threshold crossing but is there anyway I can accomplish this just with code, without the need for any external hardware??? An image is attached:

[image]

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What frequency range are you expecting? If very low, software only solution should work but if high then I would not count on software only and particularly if the MCU is expected to perform other tasks. What is "low" and "high" is not absolute and depends also on processor capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Of course:

```
bool is_high = false;
int threshold = 600; // (or whatever)
unsigned long start_time = 0;

void loop()
{
    int val = analogRead(A2);

    if (!is_high)
    {
        if (val > threshold) {
            is_high = true;
            unsigned long now = millis();
            if (start_time != 0) {
                Serial.print("t=");
                Serial.prinln(now - start_time);
            }
            start_time = now;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (val < threshold) {
            is_high= false;
        }
    }
```